# contains() method in AbstractCollection

Tags: java, collections, contains

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
        Iterator<E> it = iterator();
        if (o==null) {
            while (it.hasNext())
                if (it.next()==null)
                    return true;
        } else {
            while (it.hasNext())
                if (o.equals(it.next()))
                    return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have a question contains() method in AbstractCollection. 
I think the above implementation is equal as follow:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
        Iterator<E> it = iterator();
            while (it.hasNext())
                if (it.next().equals(o))
                    return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think there is no need to differentiate using null. Why seperated by null and not null? thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the collection contains a null-element, the call to it.next() will return null. So the expression:

```
it.next().equals(o)
```

will throw a NullPointerException